# Хранение json в реляционной БД

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, архитектура

Здравствуйте.
У меня возникла следующая ситуация. Есть проект, в нём, само собой есть классы, представляюшие таблицы из БД(сущности). Сейчас для всех пользователей представлен одинаковый функционал, но в будущем возможно для отдельных пользователелей функционал будет модифицироваться. И если с бизнес-логикой довольно просто: можно просто подключать нужные менеджеры и т.д. То вот с хранением каких-то дополнителтных данных возникают сложности, ведь таких модификаций может много и если для каждой делать своё поле(например модифицирует класс пользователя и добавляется поля "предпочтение", "интересы" и т.д.), то таблицы будут раздеваться до огромных размеров.
Собственно, идея такая: в каждой таблице сделать поле "модификации" и туда в формате json писать данные, которые уже бизнес-логикой будут разбираться.

Вот только хранение json в базе звучит как костыль( Какие вообще варианты есть?

Comment: Например Entity–attribute–value model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: @Sergey, не успел оформить)

Comment: Многие хранят json в базе и не видят в этом ничего плохого. Более того, основные СУБД уже поддерживают json нативно и позволяют проводить над ним всякие хитрые операции

Comment: Хранить JSON в базе не зазорно, но тут стоит вопрос: нужно ли вам работать с этими значениями характеристик или нет. Если Вам необходимо будет сделать выборку сущностей с определенныым значением определенного свойства, то JSON тут не очень рулит если мы не говорим о базах которые умеют с ним работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант паттерн EAV или **Entity-Attribute-Value**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/45935/

---

- В одной таблице храните сущности
- В другой таблице храните список доп.характеристик.
- В третьей их значения, ссыылаясь на необходимую сущность и на необходимую характеристику

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]